# change image color in TabBar Flutter

Tags: flutter

When clicking on the image they change color, it just doesn't change if you drag with your finger, could someone help me with the icons change color when the user also wants to drag with the finger, this below is the code.

```
                SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                        handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                            context),
                        sliver: SliverAppBar(
                          pinned: true,
                          floating: true,
                          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                          forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                          bottom: TabBar(
                            onTap: (value) {
                              WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                                setState(() {
                                  index=value;
                                });
                              });
                            },
                            tabs: [
                              Tab(
                                icon: SizedBox(
                                  height: 25,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    AppImages.fix,
                                    color:
                                        index == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.blue,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Tab(
                                icon: SizedBox(
                                  height: 25,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    AppImages.home,
                                    color:
                                        index == 1 ? Colors.white : Colors.blue,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

[image]

Comment: Can we see the complete code for the page. The code for your pages...Are you using a Pageview widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the official documentation on how to implement `TabBar`:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html

Comment: find more about [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Comment: In principle you're right, but as I refer to the most official documentation, I feel like this is ok

Comment: I am just referring the rules and better readability, hope you did check the attached link, yes official link  are useful, but it is necessary to provide exact point where it need so changes, your answer is more like comment imo

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
 
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            final TabController tabController =
                DefaultTabController.of(context)!;
            tabController.addListener(() {
              if (!tabController.indexIsChanging) {
                setState(() {});
              }
            });
            return NestedScrollView(
              headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                return [
                  SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                    handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                        context),
                    sliver: SliverAppBar(
                      pinned: true,
                      floating: true,
                      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                      forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                      bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.home,
                            color: tabController.index == 0
                                ? Colors.red
                                : Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.light,
                            color: tabController.index == 1
                                ? Colors.red
                                : Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ),
                  )
                ];
              },
              body: TabBarView(
                controller: tabController,
                children: const [
                  Center(
                    child: Text('page 1'),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text('page 2'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A friend of mine helped me